# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
(SELECT 
   Dbo.DecryptString(LastName) + '', '' +
   Dbo.DecryptString(FirstName) as PatientName 
 FROM Persons.Informations 
 WHERE PersonId = (SELECT PersonId 
                   FROM Patients.Informations 
                   WHERE PatientId = TST.PatientId))
From Transactions.SessionTransaction TST ON TST.PaymentId = TP.PaymentId
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with this query?

Why does it through the error:

> "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `IN` predicate instead of `=`, in case you have to compare multiple values returned by the `WHERE` clause, so in your query, instead of

```
  WHERE PersonId = (SELECT PersonId 
                       FROM Patients.Informations 
                       WHERE PatientId = TST.PatientId)
```

Try this instead:

```
  ...
  WHERE PersonId IN (SELECT PersonId 
                       FROM Patients.Informations 
                       WHERE PatientId = TST.PatientId)
  ...
```

However, you can `JOIN` the tables directly, instead of this predicate `IN`, like so:

```
SELECT 
   ...
FROM Persons.Informations i
INNER JOIN Transactions.SessionTransaction TST ON i.PersonId = TST.PersonId
INNER JOIN ... TP ON TST.PaymentId = TP.PaymentId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to combine the last and first names together, separated by a comma, you have too many quote marks:

```
(SELECT 
   Dbo.DecryptString(LastName) + ', ' +
   Dbo.DecryptString(FirstName) as PatientName 
 FROM Persons.Informations 
 WHERE PersonId = (SELECT PersonId 
                   FROM Patients.Informations 
                   WHERE PatientId = TST.PatientId))
From Transactions.SessionTransaction TST ON TST.PaymentId = TP.PaymentId
```

Your original query is trying to return two columns - the last name with an empty string appended to it (effectively a no-op), and the first name with an empty string prepended to it (again, effectively a no-op).